# Implement Broadcast receiver inside a Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, internet-connection

I want to check Internet connection throughout the run time of my Android application. I tried using services but seems like it is not the best option. Is there any possible way for me to implement a broadcast receiver with in a service? Or do I have to give up the service and use broadcast receivers alone?

Comment: Why the connection check in Service? Why not on each http/ https request?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Pankaj Kumar;  actually it is online streaming, so need to keep checking the connection every second

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will show you how to create SMS receiver in a service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    BwlLog.begin(TAG);
    super.onCreate();

    SMSreceiver mSmsReceiver = new SMSreceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    filter.addAction(SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION); // SMS
    filter.addAction(WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION); // MMS
    this.registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, filter);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

   /**
 * This class used to monitor SMS
 */
class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (TextUtils.equals(intent.getAction(), SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION)) {
             //handle sms receive
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i also need to declare my receiver in the Manifest file?

Comment: @AlexSanchez you don't need to declare it in the mainifest file

Comment: OK, I know I'm very late to ask here, but what if I need to send the result from onReceive back to the service? I've been struggling to solve this issue, with no luck!

Comment: I have an activity which sends an SMS. Do I have to use `sendBroadcast()` or `startService()` to call the service class, which also includes the broadcast receiver as you've mentioned in your code?

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't be wise to check for the connectivity every second. Alternatively you can listen to the action (**ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION**) and identify if you are connected to an active network or not.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
```

Additionally you can check the network Type that is currently active(Type_WIFI, Type_MOBILE)

This way, you don't need a service that keeps checking the connectivity every second.

Comment: Think this would help. It will be more helpful if you can refer me to some example code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use `Service` or `BroadCastReceiver` for this purpose. Just check Connection status everyTime you need to ping the server.

you can write a method which checks this and returns a `boolean`(true/false) according to connection status.
Below method does the same.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context mContext) {

        try {
            final ConnectivityManager conn_manager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo network_info = conn_manager
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (network_info != null && network_info.isConnected()) {
                if (network_info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                    return true;
                else if (network_info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AndroidEnthusiast; in my code i always have to use internet connection, actually it is online streaming, so need to keep check the connection every second